# How to compare URLs when one is in /Users/john format and other in file://localhost/Users/etc

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am enumerating through directories which returns URLs in the form:

```
file://localhost/Users/john/Documents/static.gif
```

I want to check these results against URLs in the form of:

```
/Users/john
```

Specifically, I want to know if the first URL is contained in the second.

I've been going through the various NSURL methods and can't find a method that will allow me to convert one form into the other for easy comparison, or actually do the comparison for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `path` method to get the strings. The first URL will become `@"/localhost/Users/john/Documents/static.gif"` and second remains the same.

You can check where second URL contains the first using,

```
if ( [[URL1 path] hasPrefix:[URL2 path]] ) {
    NSLog(@"Contained");
}
```